# How to cache API response using Cache and update method in Angular?

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps

I'm new to PWA and Service Workers, in my Angular App i have a main screen where i show a list of clients get from my API.

The component shows a list with the logo of the client and data about it.

The issue is that all images are in get from the server in base64 so after every refresh it takes very long to get all of them and i would be able to cache that data so that after the user refreshes the webpage he will still see the list of client without making a new request to the server while it will get the new data in background and it will be visible only on the new user access.

I was trying to cache my API by doing adding a dataGroup like this:

```
  "dataGroups": [
    {
      "name": "API",
      "urls": ["/api/*"],
      "cacheConfig": {
        "maxAge": "0u",
        "strategy": "freshness",
        "maxSize": 100
      }
    }
  ]
```

And in my component in ngInit i take the resourses like this:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {

    combineLatest([this.negoziService.negozi(), this.negoziService.images()]).subscribe(([nagozi, images]) => {
      this.arrNegozi = nagozi;
      images.map((img) => {
        const negozio = this.arrNegozi.find((d) => d.id === img.id);
        negozio !== undefined ? negozio.logo = 'data:image/jpg;base64,' + img.img : negozio.logo = 'assets/images/no_image.svg';
      })
      },
      error => {
        this.errore = error;
      }
    )
  }
```

Comment: Di you think about using custom interceptors ? or Rxjs operator replay for caching mechanism ?

Comment: I think using indexed DB is the best option for you

Answer (score 1):

have you looked at using a different strategy? Here are the [related docs](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-config#strategy)

```json
"dataGroups": [
    {
      "name": "API",
      "urls": ["/api/*"],
      "cacheConfig": {
        "maxAge": "1d", // 1 day
        "strategy": "performance", // use cached resources
        "maxSize": 100
      }
    }
  ]
```

Comment: in this case if the API has new items to be provided will the website show still only the cached items? like i have an ecommerce with 5 items in it to be sold then those items are cached via performance strategy, from the CMS the Admins adds a new item, when the page is refreshed what i will see?

Comment: it will get it from the cache until the `maxAge` for that item is hit or it is pushed out of the cache by `maxSize` and lots of requests. 

alternate if you are getting a list of ids from the server you could get that by fresh and cache a call to get item by id. This would be pretty chatty though for first loads.